# Remove default padding between FilledButton and Container

Tags: flutter, flutter-container, flutter-button

I am starting on Flutter and I have a small UI issue that I cannot find a way to fix.

There is a small margin between the button and the container that I would like to remove.

[image]

Below is my code:

```
Widget _signInOrSignUpSelector() {
    return Container(
        //height: 105,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: FoodlooseColors.cOrange.withOpacity(0.3),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
        ),
        child: Center(
            child: Row(children: [
          Expanded(child: _signInSelectorButton()),
          Expanded(
            child: _signUpSelectorButton(),
          )
        ])));
  }

  Widget _signInSelectorButton() {
    return FilledButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          isLogin = !isLogin;
        });
      },
      style: FilledButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor: isLogin ? FoodlooseColors.cOrange : Colors.transparent,
      ),
      child: const Text("Sign-In"),
    );
  }

  Widget _signUpSelectorButton() {
    return FilledButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            isLogin = !isLogin;
          });
        },
        style: FilledButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor:
              isLogin ? Colors.transparent : FoodlooseColors.cOrange,
        ),
        child: const Text("Sign-Up"));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                child: _signInOrSignUpSelector()),
            _entryField('email', _emailController),
            _entryField('password', _passwordController),
            _errorMessage(),
            _submitButton(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Any idea how to remove the extra padding ?

Answer (score 0):

When you want children widgets to fill `Row` and `Column`. You need to use `CrossAxisAlignment` and `MainAxisAlignment` properties. So it provide how children widget align in parent widget. Please check these documents. [MainAxisAlignment](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/MainAxisAlignment.html) and [CrossAxisAlignment](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CrossAxisAlignment.html)

I have adjusted your code that will stretch in vertical as you needed.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    height: double.infinity,
    width: double.infinity,
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, << Here
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
            child: _signInOrSignUpSelector()),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}

Widget _signInOrSignUpSelector() {
return Container(
    height: 50, << Here
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.3),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
    ),
    child: Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, <<Here
      children: [
        Expanded(child: _signInSelectorButton()),
        Expanded(child: _signUpSelectorButton())
      ],
    ));
}
```

[image: SignIn and Signup buttons]